# Problem with non-linear regression with low r-squared value

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I am trying to fit a nonlinear regression line on my dataset but the fitted line looks odd as it starts from middle of y-axis and thus R-squared value is also quite low (the blue line r2=50). I think if I can modify it to the *red line* it may result in a better r-squared. Is that right?

**data:**

```
    x <- c(72925.54, 1169812.77, 62098.7, 567929.36, 46506.39, 275755.22, 
31651.06, 17552.06, 6065.29, 52617.75, 32729.35, 50706.11, 6169.27, 
4360.01, 26799.12, 20747.9, 15518.09, 26800.22, 67470.81, 613530.49, 
4813.84, 17286.46, 1537712.05, 1466311.98, 18952.34, 49014.31, 
1408119.34, 160026.59, 17802.44, 447694.5, 18220.26, 13113.15, 
10206.27, 415138.24, 1572750.08, 140690.08, 16414.01, 51985.79, 
2025197.14)

    y <- c(30.66, 48.66, 49.92, 14.63, 7.77, 35.79, 25.1, 4.59, 8.26, 
8.99, 33.49, 15.94, 6.32, 11.78, 10.77, 28.08, 9.33, 37.26, 53.99, 
25.72, 40.54, 44.26, 48.62, 26.07, 28.32, 36.21, 53.59, 33.42, 
39.2, 70.21, 39.16, 34.65, 36.5, 55.87, 47.59, 46.09, 34.38, 
29.79, 53.1)

#my df
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

**Scripts:**

```
library(ggplot2)
p2 <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  xlab("x axis") + ylab("y axis") +
  geom_point(color = 'black', alpha = 0.5, size=2) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm", formula = y ~ (log(x)), colour = 'blue', size = 2)+
  theme_tq() +
  labs(title = "Plot 1")

p2

#calculating r-squared
yy <- predict(lm(y ~ log(x), data = df))
r2 <- cor(y, yy)^2
```

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you are right but I suggest you first plot it on the log scale.

Comment: That is not a nonlinear regression. And, how have you fitted the red line? If you have another model, compute its r-squared?

Comment: @ Rui the red line is just an assumption. I have now plotted this on log-scale as @Roland suggested and do not think I can improve it much but what I saw! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My equation search turned up the two-parameter equation"y = a + b * ln(x)" with parameters a = -1.6833016837382591E+01 and b = 4.4249791262770692E+00 yielding RMSE = 14.1 and R-squared = 0.241

[image: plot]

Comment: Looks great! can you please also add the code to this graph so I can also accept it as the right answer?